# IOS - Tapped on TabBarItem, check variable to show corresponding ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Please help me find solution for case:

I have `UITabBarController` in storyboard. When I tap on a TabBarItem (index 1), I should check variable (int)'ShowVC' to show corresponding view controller.
E.g:

```
switch (ShowVC) {
            case 1:
                showViewController1;
                break;
            case 2:
                showViewController2;
                break;
            case 3:
                showViewController3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

So, what is solution for it?

Where can I add check method to show view controller when tapped TabBarItem?

Answer (score 0):

This link will definitely help.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/ios-tab-bar-controller-example.html

Comment: No, you don't understand my question. You tap on tab bar item 1, you check and show VC1 or VC2 or VC3 depend variable 'ShowVC'. Do not tab bar item 1 show VC1, tab bar item 2 show VC2, ...

Comment: Describe more in detail what you want to do.

Comment: I need to check authority of user to show corresponding View Controllers

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you need to get Notification when your Tab is clicked or Tapped.

in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBar setDelegate:self];
```

Now in `didSelectViewController` you can write your logic or condition about what to display.

```
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //Write your logic here
   tabBarController.selectedViewController = yourNewController;
}
```